# App lists cut off on Stack Apps on mobile with desktop view

Tags: bug, stackapps, mobile-safari, ios

I am on iOS Safari and I can’t horizontally scroll and see everything on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, this means that I can only read part of the description.

This happens on any page that lists apps.

Comment: If you "disable responsiveness" in the footer it will at least let you side scroll. I'm guessing that their app icons are throwing off the responsive layout.

Comment: @john This is the “full site”/“desktop version” which you can see by clicking the link in the footer

Comment: It happens in my phone.